# How to make Ranorex detect SAP?

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex, sap

I have Ranorex 6.2.0 and I want to automate SAP. I already followed [the instructions](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/technology-instrumentation/testing-of-sap-applications.html), so I have

- SAP scripting enabled on server side (transaction RZ10, `sapgui/user_scripting`to `TRUE`)
- restarted the server
- SAP scripting enabled in SAPLogon
- restarted the client

However, when I run the test, I get an error

> This control (from process 'saplogon') seems to be a Windows Forms control, but was not recognized as such, possibly due to a security limitation. UI element identification capabilities for this control may be limited.
>
> If this control is a WinForms control, please make sure that the automating process has the rights to access the automated application. Otherwise, please ignore this limitation.
>   Process: 'saplogon' (pid 3532)
>
> The following website provides more information on this technology limitation:
>   http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/technology-instrumentation/general-troubleshooting.html#c3250

I have checked all the relevant reasons in the linked website, but could not find a solution. How do I make Ranorex recognize SAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Windows Control panel, Add/Remove programs, then click Change.

[image: Change Installation]

Next, go to the custom setup and uncheck the item "Ranorex Exe Manifest files". Note how the text mentions that this shall not be installed for SAP automation.

Restart the PC.

[image: Ranorex Setup]